# Mysql error (42000) Unknown database 'testdb' while trying to connect to mysql remotely from another machine

Tags: mysql, maven-3

Dears ,
I have two Virtual machines **App1** & **db** ...
I installed **Mysql** in **db machine** ,  and I am trying on **App1 machine** to build EAR for **springboot-demo-app** following steps in this link (*https://github.com/Mhussein27/springboot-demo-app*)

**But** I am stuck in the step (mvn package) on app1 machine after exporting Mysql Configuration like the below , I am facing **Unknown database error** :

```
export APP_DATABASE_USER=testuser
export APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=XXX
export APP_DATABASE_URL='jdbc:mysql://db:3306/testdb'
admin@app1:~/springboot-demo-app$ mvn package
```

**Error:**

```
Unable to obtain database connection
------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 1049
Message    : Unknown database 'testdb'
```

on **db machine** I can see the testuser and the testdb schema and privileges are fine !

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;

+---------------+-----------+
| User          | Host      |
+---------------+-----------+
| testuser      | %         |
| mysql.session | localhost |
| mysql.sys     | localhost |
| root          | localhost |
+---------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| testdb             |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testuser'@'%';

+------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for testuser@%                                |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%'        |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'testuser'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)




mysql> show tables;

+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_testdb      |
+-----------------------+
| flyway_schema_history |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please let me know what is wrong !!

Comment: Make sure you're run [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flush.html#flush-privileges), after you make changes to users.

Comment: You need to check in the following order: 1) Connectivity, like ping from you dev machine into you remote db machine, 2) Check that the mysql port is exposed to the internet, and 3) Check if you can connect to your remote machine directly from you dev terminal `mysql -u testuser -h <database server ip address> -p`